# Drupal 7 - disabling / removing administration from production server

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

We are being asked whether it's possible to have the administration of Drupal completely removed if a site is hosted on a production environment, but have it available on a pre-production environment that would put content / modules to the same production DB.

My initial thoughts are - no.

As I understand it, the administration system IS drupal. The best solution we could recommend is to

- Disable the admin menu and overlay on the production servers
- Use .htaccess files on the production servers to deny any requests to Drupal's admin paths e.g. /user /users /admin
- On the pre-production server, use .htaccess files again to restrict access by IP address.
- Setup appropriate user accounts and roles in drupal.

Is there something really obvious I'm missing, or can anyone suggest alternative solutions to the problem?

Comment: That's what the permissions system is for. If you want to stop anyone from logging in, you can just disable the 'user/login' path

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to understand what the real problem is. Customers ask in a language they understand and we should answer in the same way. 
Technically answer is "no", but as you already pointed there are many options to achieve that. If in production nobody should be able to login and manage content you can simply disable all users. 
I have similar solution. In production site we have only admin user and deploy user active. All other users are disabled.

If you really want /admin not to be accessible you can put this code in you settings.php:

```
if (0 === strpos($_GET['q'], 'admin')) {
  die();
}
```